# How to find index of a method in an interface?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

How can I find index of procedure/function which is defined in Interface? Can it be done with RTTI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all we need to enumerate the methods of the interface. Unfortunately this program

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Rtti;

type
  IMyIntf = interface
    procedure Foo;
  end;

procedure EnumerateMethods(IntfType: TRttiInterfaceType);
var
  Method: TRttiMethod;
begin
  for Method in IntfType.GetDeclaredMethodsdo
    Writeln('Name: ' + Method.Name + 'Index: ' + IntToStr(Method.VirtualIndex));
end;

var
  ctx: TRttiContext;

begin
  EnumerateMethods(ctx.GetType(TypeInfo(IMyIntf)) as TRttiInterfaceType);
end.
```

produces no output.

This question covers this issue: [Delphi TRttiType.GetMethods return zero TRttiMethod instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004045/delphi-trttitype-getmethods-return-zero-trttimethod-instances).

If you read down to the bottom of that question an answer states that compiling with `{$M+}` will lead to sufficient RTTI being emitted.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$M+}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Rtti;

type
  IMyIntf = interface
    procedure Foo(x: Integer);
    procedure Bar(x: Integer);
  end;

procedure EnumerateMethods(IntfType: TRttiInterfaceType);
var
  Method: TRttiMethod;
begin
  for Method in IntfType.GetDeclaredMethods do
    Writeln('Name: ' + Method.Name + 'Index: ' + IntToStr(Method.VirtualIndex));
end;

var
  ctx: TRttiContext;

begin
  EnumerateMethods(ctx.GetType(TypeInfo(IMyIntf)) as TRttiInterfaceType);
end.
```

The output is:

```
Name: FooIndex: 3
Name: BarIndex: 4
```

Remember that all interfaces derive from `IInterface`. So one might expect its members to appear. However, it seems that `IInterface` is compiled in `{$M-}` state. It also seems that the methods are enumerated in order, although I've no reason to believe that is guaranteed.

Thanks to @RRUZ for pointing out the existence of [`VirtualIndex`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TRttiMethod.VirtualIndex).

Comment: Makes me wonder how inherited/overridden ones would be listed.

Comment: @JerryDodge We are talking about interfaces

Comment: Yes, I know this. Interfaces can be inherited (and redeclared methods rather)

Comment: @Jerry You said overridden. And interface inheritance isn't much more than adding extra functions on the end of the parent interface.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, you can use the `VirtualIndex` property to get the index of the method like so `Writeln(Format('Name: %s Index %d', [Method.Name, Method.VirtualIndex]));`

Comment: @RRUZ Can you make an example with actual interface? :)

Comment: @John Just add that code into the code in my answer. I'll update it soon.