# How to hook COM interfaces?

Tags: delphi, com, delphi-xe7

How can I properly hook COM interfaces in Delphi? The following code should work but it crashes when I try to call the original function.

First chance exception at $725E1C46. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x725e1c46: write of address 0x725de532'. Process Project.exe (6524)

```
unit ComHook;

interface

uses
    Winapi.Windows,
    Winapi.WinInet,
    ComObj,
    ComServ,
    ActiveX,
    UrlMon,
    MSHTML,
    SHDocVw,
    DDetours;

const
    CLSID_HttpProtocol: TGUID = '{79EAC9E2-BAF9-11CE-8C82-00AA004BA90B}';

type
  TInternetProtocol = record
    class function Read(pv: Pointer; cb: ULONG; out cbRead: ULONG): HResult;  static;
    class function Seek(dlibMove: LARGE_INTEGER; dwOrigin: DWORD; out libNewPosition: ULARGE_INTEGER): HResult; static;
    class function LockRequest(dwOptions: DWORD): HResult;  static;
    class function UnlockRequest: HResult; static;
  end;

var
    FInternetProtocol: IInternetProtocol;
    FRead: function(pv: Pointer; cb: ULONG; out cbRead: ULONG): HResult;
    FSeek: function(dlibMove: LARGE_INTEGER; dwOrigin: DWORD; out libNewPosition: ULARGE_INTEGER): HResult;
    FLockRequest: function(dwOptions: DWORD): HResult;
    FUnlockRequest: function: HResult;

implementation

{ TInternetProtocol }

class function TInternetProtocol.Read(pv: Pointer; cb: ULONG; out cbRead: ULONG): HResult;
begin
  Result := FRead(pv, cb, cbRead);
end;

class function TInternetProtocol.Seek(dlibMove: LARGE_INTEGER; dwOrigin: DWORD; out libNewPosition: ULARGE_INTEGER): HResult;
begin
  Result := FSeek(dlibMove, dwOrigin, libNewPosition);
end;

class function TInternetProtocol.LockRequest(dwOptions: DWORD): HResult;
begin
  Result := FLockRequest(dwOptions); // Crash!
end;

class function TInternetProtocol.UnlockRequest: HResult;
begin
  Result := FUnlockRequest;
end;

initialization
  CoCreateInstance(CLSID_HttpProtocol, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IInternetProtocol, FInternetProtocol);
  @FRead := InterceptCreate(FInternetProtocol, 7, @TInternetProtocol.Read);
  @FSeek := InterceptCreate(FInternetProtocol, 8, @TInternetProtocol.Seek);
  @FLockRequest := InterceptCreate(FInternetProtocol, 9, @TInternetProtocol.LockRequest);
  @FUnlockRequest := InterceptCreate(FInternetProtocol, 10, @TInternetProtocol.UnlockRequest);
end.


...

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('www.stackoverflow.com');
end;
```

Comment: Please stop changing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three mistakes that I can see:

1. You have missed the calling convention. These methods should all be `stdcall`.
2. You need to include the instance pointer as the first parameter of each method.
3. Your indices are wrong. You need to count from zero and account for the three methods of `IInterface`.

After the changes your code should look like this:

```
type
  TInternetProtocol = record
    class function Read(inst: Pointer; pv: Pointer; cb: ULONG; out cbRead: ULONG): HResult; stdcall; static;
    class function Seek(inst: Pointer; dlibMove: LARGE_INTEGER; dwOrigin: DWORD; out libNewPosition: ULARGE_INTEGER): HResult; stdcall; static;
    class function LockRequest(inst: Pointer; dwOptions: DWORD): HResult; stdcall; static;
    class function UnlockRequest(inst: Pointer): HResult; stdcall; static;
  end;

var
    FInternetProtocol: IInternetProtocol;
    FRead: function(inst: Pointer; pv: Pointer; cb: ULONG; out cbRead: ULONG): HResult; stdcall;
    FSeek: function(inst: Pointer; dlibMove: LARGE_INTEGER; dwOrigin: DWORD; out libNewPosition: ULARGE_INTEGER): HResult; stdcall;
    FLockRequest: function(inst: Pointer; dwOptions: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
    FUnlockRequest: function(inst: Pointer): HResult; stdcall;

....

@FRead := InterceptCreate(FInternetProtocol, 9, @TInternetProtocol.Read);
@FSeek := InterceptCreate(FInternetProtocol, 10, @TInternetProtocol.Seek);
@FLockRequest := InterceptCreate(FInternetProtocol, 11, @TInternetProtocol.LockRequest);
@FUnlockRequest := InterceptCreate(FInternetProtocol, 12, @TInternetProtocol.UnlockRequest);
```

FWIW, the latest version of the Delphi Detours library allows you to hook interface methods by name which makes life a little simpler.

Comment: So you decided to omit it?!!

Comment: Not really omit it. More like forgot to mention it.

Comment: How can you forget? Didn't you use the clipboard to post the code? Or is this not the code that you are using?

Comment: Yes I tried hooking by name but it also crashes >.<

Comment: If I were you I would start with a simple interface of your own making and prove that you can hook that. Then move on to the real problem.

Comment: The indices were indeed the problem. Could you mention also how can we get the index by name? Would help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: The latest version of Delphi Detours library has the code to do that. I think you can read that. Plus there was a question here on that subject recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969212/how-to-find-index-of-a-method-in-an-interface/27969309#27969309

Comment: By the way your indices crash it. Should be from 9-12. Thats wininet hooking. :)

Comment: Thanks. I'd assumed that you had counted starting from `0` at the first method of `IInternetProtocolRoot`. But I guess you'd started from `1`.